# How to limit output to only 3 rows with each_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here goes the result on many different numbers, and how to limit output to only 3 rows

```
<% @user.dids.each_with_index{ |did, i| %>
<li><%= did.did %></li>
<% } %>
```

**Result**

```
<li>number 123123123</li>
<li>number 123123123</li>
<li>number 123123123</li>
<li>number 123123123</li>
<li>number 123123123</li>
```

but I want if user has more than 3 numbers:

```
<li>number 123123123</li>
<li>number 123123123</li>
<li>number 123123123</li>
<li>and more</li>
```

Comment: You need to handle this through query and html

Comment: do you want to show all remaining list on click 'and more' or do you want to show next 3 results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @user.dids.first(3).each{ |did| %>
```

will only get you only the first three

Then you can do an

```
 <% if @user.dids.count > 3 %>
   <li>and more</li>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: but how limit maximum 3 rows and the fourth row, <li>and more</li>

Comment: This code does exactly that. I assume you realize that since you accepted my answer.  If something is still not clear, let me know.

Comment: all is good, I just didn't see the code `.first(3)` thanks Devin :-)